# Run pre-commit and pre-push commands in docker via husky

Tags: git, docker, npm, yarnpkg, husky

How can git-hook commands (like `yarn test`) be run inside of Docker via Husky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. This goes in `package.json`:

```
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "docker run --rm -v \"$PWD\":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:alpine yarn test",
    "pre-push": "docker run --rm -v \"$PWD\":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:alpine yarn test"
  }
}
```

Comment: @lewislbr, yes, you need to have `node` installed locally. In addition, you need to install the dependencies since `husky` relies upon `node_modules`. Therefore, the whole point of containerizing the app is missed.